# How to get choices field from django models in a list?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model having choices field. I want to fetch the choices options in a list.

How can I achieve that?

```py
OPTIONS = (
    ('COOL', 'COOL'),
    ('WARM', 'WARM'),
)
class My_Model(models.Model):
     options = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=OPTIONS, default=None,blank=True, null=True)
```

I want options values in a list like ['COOL','WARM'], How to achieve it, I tried something like My_Model.options but it is not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can obtain the data with:

```
>>> My_Model.options.field.choices
(('COOL', 'COOL'), ('WARM', 'WARM'))
```

you thus can get a list of keys with:

```
>>> [c[0] for c in My_Model.options.field.choices]
['COOL', 'WARM']
```

and use `c[1]` if you want the value (the part that is rendered  for that choice).

Answer (score 1):

I checked the above code but it's giving me error on .field

So i tried other code and that code is working for me.

```
[OPTIONS[c][0] for c in range(len(OPTIONS))]
```

['COOL', 'WARM']

Answer (score 0):

```
[choice[1] for choice in OPTIONS]
```

get

```
['COOL', 'WARM']
```

Hint
We usually don't make choices like this

**Not preferred:**

```
OPTIONS = (
            ('COOL', 'COOL'),
            ('WARM', 'WARM'),
        )
```

**I usually prefer this :**

```
OPTIONS = (
    ('0', 'COOL'),
    ('1', 'WARM'),
)
```

and make `max_length =1` or two if choices more than 9